# Not able to insert values into SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, android-sqlite, sql-insert

Very new to Java coding/Android app development. I'm trying to make an app which will take in information data and use SQLite to manage it. Right now, when I try adding info, nothing is entered and when I view the database I get "No data found".

This is the code in my `DatabaseHelper`:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "userinfo";
    public static final String COL_1 = "AGE";
    public static final String COL_2 = "SEX";
    public static final String COL_3 = "HEIGHT";
    public static final String COL_4 = "WEIGHT";
    public static final String COL_5 = "TYPE";
    public static final String COL_6 = "ACTIVITY";
    public String str = null;

    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public DatabaseHelper db;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (AGE INTEGER, SEX TEXT, HEIGHT INTEGER, WEIGHT INTEGER, TYPE INTEGER, ACTIVITY INTEGER)");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(Integer age, String sex) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, age);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, sex);
        long result = database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public boolean insertData2(Integer height, Integer weight, Integer type) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_3,height);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,weight);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,type);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public boolean insertData3(Integer activity) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_6,activity);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

The three different "InsertData" are for three activities which need to add data to the database. Is that the right way to do it? Also here is the activity which calls the first "InsertData".

```
public class info1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    EditText editText13,editText14;
    Button btnAddData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_info1);

        editText13 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText13);
        editText14 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText14);
        btnAddData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
    }

    public void AddData() {
        btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(Integer.parseInt(editText13.getText().toString()),editText14.getText().toString() );
                        if(isInserted == true)
                            Toast.makeText(info1.this, "Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(info1.this, "Data Not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void NextPage2(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(info1.this, info2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I've been at it for hours but I don't know what to change...

Comment: Have you put breakpoints or logs in your insert method to see what happens in there?

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be calling the `AddData` method, so the onClickListener is not added.

After the line

```
        btnAddData = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
```

Add a new line

```
        AddData();
```

Comment: Well that definitely helped I think, the app crashes now when the button is clicked which is good. That means at least the button click is doing something and it's just the code that needs to be fixed. Thanks, I will add logs as per @codeMagic 's suggestion and see if I can get it working from that!